# Why does the Augmented Dickey fuller test not use the F-test for checking stationarity

Tags: time-series

As I understand the F-test is much better suited for analyzing linear regression models, so why does the ADF test not use the F-test rather using the T-test for hypothesis testing.

Answer (score 2):

The T-test is actually a special case of the F-test.  If you examine the tables (or computer return for F and T) and compare the F distribution with one numerator degree of freedom to the T distribution (2-sided) with d.f. equal to the denominator d.f. of the F, you will see that the F values are the squares of the T values (or the p-values are the same when comparing T-squared to F).

So for the two-tailed case with 1 d.f. (1 coefficient, comparing 2 groups, ...) they are the same, the T-test has the advantage of being able to do a one-tailed comparison where the standard F is always testing any difference (though there are ways to do it directionally, but that takes more work than using the T).

Answer (score 0):

In ADF test, neither T-test nor the F-test is used. T-statistic is calculated but unlike in normal linear models with standard assumptions it doesn't follow the t-distribution. Same goes for the F-statistic.

Critical values for these statistics are taken from DF table.